# Selenium - WebElement.Click(), page refreshes but not loading

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using pagefactory and selenium 3 with Java, I have created a simple script to login and logout. I have used the below for explicit wait:

```
public void verifyElementisEnabled( WebElement wElement,String sFieldName){     

    printCurrentDate();
    try{

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(wElement));          
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(wElement));
        **//Thread.Sleep("1000") - Script works if this line is uncommented**
        if (wElement.isEnabled()==true)
            System.out.println(sFieldName + " is enabled");
        printCurrentDate();

    }catch (Exception e){

        printCurrentDate();
        System.out.println(sFieldName + " is NOT enabled");                     
        Assert.fail(sFieldName +  " Field not found", e);
    }       
}
```

The issue I'm facing is, for the Logout, after the webelement click, the page refreshes briefly for a second but the appropriate Login page is not displayed, instead it stays in the same page. I don't see any exception for weblement before click. Below is the code snippet.

However all of this works if I use **"Thread.Sleep(1000)"** in the above "VerifyElementisEnabled method (anything less than 1000 is not working)

```
@Test
public void Test1(){
    LoginPage objLogin = new LoginPage(driver);
    objLogin.setUserName();
    objLogin.setPwd();
    HomePage objHome = objLogin.clickLoginButton();
    objHome.confirmHomePage();
    objLogin = objHome.SignOut();
    objLogin.verifyLoginPage();
}

public LoginPage SignOut(){
    commonLib.click_webelement(SignOut,"Sign Out");
    commonLib.waitForPagetoLoadJS_Ajax();
    return new LoginPage(driver);
}
```

Wait for JS and Ajax method, just verifies if the document.ready status is complete.

I'm out of ideas here, any suggestions or help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Updated:

```
public void confirmHomePage(){
    commonLib.verifyElementisEnabled(titleText, "User Search");

}
```

Final update:
Looks like the parent class Test1 given above had issues. After performing the tests, the webdriver was returning to the previous page "Login". Here I was returning the "Login Page" class. This was obstructing with the page navigation. I updated the Test1 as below:

```
public void afcDealerTest1(){
    LoginPage objLogin = new LoginPage(driver);
    objLogin.enterLoginCredentials();
    HomePage objHome = objLogin.clickLoginButton();
    objHome.confirmHomePage();
    objHome.SignOut(); //<-- Refer to this line
    objLogin.verifyLoginPage();
}
```

Also removed all the thread.sleep in all the methods, except for the JS Ready status as complete with a 200ms sleep. It seems to be working fine.

Thanks everyone for all the help.

Comment: Please show the function code which will call `verifyElementisEnabled()` inside.

Comment: Do not use Thread.Sleep(1000).It's not a best practice. What will happen, if for some reason the timeout change to 1001s? Your test starts to fail, and u don't know why. You can create custom wait function with a while loop, add a condition specific to a time frame, and check for updates in each second. If max time is achieved, and the element is not visible/changed, the test must fail.

Comment: @yong, added the method in the main post.

Comment: @Zhivko.Kostadinov, I agree that's why I've commented that sleep command. I had a while loop with    if(wElement.isDisplayed()==true)
and it always turned up as True. There is something else that I'm missing I guess.

Comment: @swame,  Please show the HTML of the `Logout`, I suspect it implement the navigation to login page by JavaScript function which bind to the `Logout` click event.  If logout implemented like `<a href='/login'`, from cases i experienced, even the browser is busy on loading the home page, if you click the `Logout` on home page, browser still can response to your click and will navigate to login page finally.

Comment: If logout implement by javascript function,  when the logout is visible and clickable on page, maybe the browser have not complete the javascript file loading (especially in nowadays javascript tags usually put the end of web page).   thus the javascript function have not binded to the `Logout` before you click on it.

Comment: @yong, Thank you for all the replies. I have updated the main post with my findings and it seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is sync issue. It seems element gets enable after some time which bypassing your explicit conditions. You should wait till element is enable.

Comment: Yes if you could see the main post, I'm using explicit wait, There is no implicit wait and it also conditions for element.IsDisplayed and wait.until (isclickable), still no luck.

Comment: I meant to say that you might not be using correct explicit wait conditions.

Comment: Not sure what else is required, after clicking I'm waiting until the element is displayed and visibility is true, also until javascript loading is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by this modification below:

Before:

```
    @Test
public void Test1(){
    LoginPage objLogin = new LoginPage(driver);
    objLogin.setUserName();
    objLogin.setPwd();
    HomePage objHome = objLogin.clickLoginButton();
    objHome.confirmHomePage();
    objLogin = objHome.SignOut();
    objLogin.verifyLoginPage();
}
```

Fix:

```
@Test
public void Test1(){
    LoginPage objLogin = new LoginPage(driver);
    objLogin.setUserName();
    objLogin.setPwd();
    HomePage objHome = objLogin.clickLoginButton();
    objHome.confirmHomePage();
```

> objHome.SignOut();

```
    objLogin.verifyLoginPage();
}
```